# Using anchors to point to a location on Google Maps

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps, anchor

I am creating a mobile website where I'm running a map with JS.
What I want to do is to have a location in an anchor, that, when you click on it will point to a location on the map.

Anyone knows if this is possible, and how?

PS: I would love to use some C# while doing this, if possible.

Kind regards, Mark Nielsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use google map api for this, see here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays

Comment: First off, thank you for responding!
I have been browsing that resource, but haven't been able to find exactly what I am looking for. Maybe you could be so kind as to point in a more definite position on the page?

Comment: hope this will help https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers

Answer (score 0):

Only viable solution is to

1. create your links with specific ids
2. bind function to a javascript    click event of the link
3. make this function display a specific marker on the page / scroll there / etc.

step 1 could be done serverside in c#

step 2 is plain javascript

step 3 is something where you have to look at the google maps api.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this :

```
protected void lbtnSeeOnGoogle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string addressQueryString = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + address.Zip + "+" + address.City + "+" + address.Province + "+" + address.Country;
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>var win = window.open('" + addressQueryString + "','_blank'); win.focus();</script>");
}
```

Comment: Response.Write is not a good way to create html output http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925123/response-write-outdated . Also your solutions involves a postback, possibly loosing all current state on the webpage. A client side solution with Javascript is the best approach.

Comment: yeah you are right , but the question asker did not specify actual requirement.  for example in my case the server side was only feasible solution. so it depends upon the scenario. there are many ways to do a job. my answer was only meant to give the asker a crude idea of how it can be done.